# switch keyboard keys while typing from english to another language

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

i am trying to force user to type using another language and i want a method that switch user input keys from English to another language. For example if the user type ABC the input should be displayed شلاس <= arabic  .

What i tried :

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" (keypress)="myMethod(myInput.value)" #myInput>
```

In ts :

```
myMethod(txt: any) {
    let yas = '';
    yas = txt.value;
    yas = yas.replace(/`/g, 'ذ');
    yas = yas.replace(/0/g, '۰');
    yas = yas.replace(/1/g, '۱');
     ..........................
    txt.value = yas;
}
```

Comment: ANd what have you tried so far ?

Comment: i am still doing a research but what i found is just translation text but what i want is translate while typing

Comment: So you ask for code that you didn't even try to find by yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702155/angularjs-translate-text-while-typing  didn't work

Comment: Yeah that's AngularJS, there is no answer, and it's not your code. For the third time, post the code you have already provided, or your question will be closed (since you don't follow [ask] directives).

Comment: @trichetriche check now

Comment: You're sending the value of your input instead of the input itself. change `myMethod(myInput.value)` to `myMethod(myInput)`

Comment: yes worked fine but last input won't convert